# I want to save a List in a .csv file. Every \n in the list should make a new line in the file

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

Example list:

```
line = ['New York;New\nBerlin;Ber\nMelbourne;Mel']
```

Every second element in my list contains a \n.

```
with open('file.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
save = csv.writer(csvfile)
y = list.count("\n")
for line in range(0, y):
    save.writerow(str(list))
```

How the .csv file should look like:

```
NewYork;New
Berlin;Ber
Melbourne;Mel
```

My Goal is to display the list in excel. This should look like this:

New York | New
Berlin   | Ber
Melbourn | Mel

| = new colum

How does the saving process needs to look like?

Comment: Your example does not constitute a syntactically valid list.

Answer (score 0):

Your list is not a Python list
it should be something like this, if it contains one string with `\n` in it.

```
lines = ["New York;New\nBerlin;Ber\nMelbourne;Mel"]
```

or like this if it contains multiple strings with '\n' in it

```
lines = ["New York;New\nBerlin;Ber\nMelbourne;Mel",
         "Ber\nMelbourne;Mel\nNew York;New\nBerlin",
         ...
         ]
```

Also it is not very clear what you are trying to achieve from the code you have written, but the question seems to be that you have a list of strings with new line characters in it, and you want to break the line at '\n' while writing it to a csv file.

the code for which is quite simple

```
import csv
# this list is explained above
lines = ["New York;New\nBerlin;Ber\nMelbourne;Mel", "New York;New\nBerlin;Ber\nMelbourne;Mel"]
lines = [[word] for line in lines for word in line.split('\n')]
with open('file.csv', 'w') as fh:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(fh)
    csv_writer.writerows(lines)
```

Additionally since you did not talk about columns, I would suggest please read on CSV files, you might not need a CSV file.

#### UPDATE

after reading your comment, I believe you have one big string of content, and the changing first two lines in above code to this should work.

```
content = "first colum first line; second colum first line \n first colum second line; second colum second line"
lines = [line.split(';') for line in content.split('\n')]
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, after every ; should be a new colum. first colum first line; second colum first line \n first colum second line etc. The ; should mak a new Colum and the \n a new line. After testing your solution i tink i still have a mistake anywere couse it toruns out every second row is a new letter. The list is now splitet into 833 rows.